# How to Restrict a Library to only one person (Manager) in a SPS Online site?

Tags: library, access

I created a department SharePoint Online site with several Libraries.  I would like to restrict ALL access and permissions for one of the libraries (Manager's Library) so that it is only accessible, viewable by the Manager.  The manager and I are both Site Owner's,  I have broken the inheritance for the Library and created a user group of Manager Restricted with only the Manager as a User in that group.  However I can still access the content in the Library.  What am I doing wrong, or how can I achieve this restriction?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Three groups of people always have access to your content, even if you have broken inheritance:

- Site Owners (They have "Full Control")
- Site Collection Administrators (you cannot hide anything from them in their site collection.)
- O365: Tenant Administrators, or On-prem: Any granted auditor or "super user" permissions.

To separate yourself from your manager, create a new subsite, break inheritance, and remove all users and groups, except for the manager, from the subsite.